# Assign different values to cell arrays in MATLAB at once

Tags: arrays, matlab, cell-array

I need help on creating a cell array in MATLAB where each cell is an array of different sizes. For example, let's assume I have this simple array and the value:

```
A = [5 3 8 7 0 4 1];
B = 10;
```

The cell array `C` must be created such that:

```
C = 
[10 20 30 40 50]
[10 20 30]
[10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80]
[10 20 30 40 50 60 70]
[Empty matrix 1x0]
[10 20 30 40]
[10]
```

Is it possible to do that in one operation only?  I have tried:

```
C = cellfun(@(a,b)b*ones(1,a), A,B)
```

but it did not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cellfun` expects a **cell array** as the input into the function.  You have a numeric array so use [`arrayfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/arrayfun.html) instead.  You are also not outputting a scalar per element in the array so you need to set the `UniformOutput` flag to 0.  Finally, use the `colon` operator to do what you need instead of matrix multiplication.  The output will unfortunately be a row vector of cells so if you absolutely need a column vector such as what you have shown in your post, transpose the output:

```
A = [5 3 8 7 0 4 1];
B = 10;
C = arrayfun(@(x) B*(1:x), A, 'UniformOutput', 0).';
```

Take note that the anonymous function declared as the first input into `arrayfun` has lexical scope, meaning that any variables that were visible in the workspace before the anonymous function declaration is visible.  You can just access that variable inside your function instead of having to manually feed it into `arrayfun` as a separate input.

We now get:

```
>> format compact
>> celldisp(C)
C{1} =
    10    20    30    40    50
C{2} =
    10    20    30
C{3} =
    10    20    30    40    50    60    70    80
C{4} =
    10    20    30    40    50    60    70
C{5} =
     []
C{6} =
    10    20    30    40
C{7} =
    10
```

Comment: Hi I forgot to say that I tried that too... it says  `Undefined function 'colon' for input arguments of type 'cell'.

Error in @(x)B*(1:x)`

Comment: @PhoenixBlue `cellfun` expects a **cell array**.  Please read my post in full.  You will notice **I did not use `cellfun`**.

Comment: OH! Sorry My bad! it worked! I just put the cell array instead of the simple array (even in my first attempt...)!! Thanks again!!

Comment: @PhoenixBlue Ah I see.  So the elements are in a cell array, like `A = {5, 3 , 8, 7, 0, 4, 1};`?  In that case, then using `cellfun` should work.  You specified a numeric array which is why `arrayfun` is required.  Glad I could help.