# Dump all values of cell array to numeric array

Tags: arrays, matlab, type-conversion, cell-array

This is following my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39394731/assign-different-values-to-cell-arrays-in-matlab-at-once) . Assuming that I finally got that cellarray:

```
C = 
[10 20 30 40 50]
[10 20 30]
[10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80]
[10 20 30 40 50 60 70]
[Empty matrix 1x0]
[10 20 30 40]
[10]
```

How can I get to dump all these values in a single numeric array like this:

```
D = [10 20 30 40 50 10 20 30 10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 10 20 30 40 50 60 70 10 20 30 40 10]
```

Thanks in advance for your input!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
D = horzcat(C{:})
```

**EDIT**

Thanks to @thewaywewalk, even simpler:

```
D = [C{:}]
```

Comment: or simply `[C{:}]`